# geocoding in R from csv - 40,000 rows

Tags: r, gis, geocode

I have a csv dataset with just over 40k rows I'm looking to geocode. I found a useful tutorial using gmap and google, but it has a limit of 2500 addresses (super annoying). Looking for a useful and clear tutorial for a way to accommodate large batches from a csv.

I am a beginner at R - appreciate any help or reference!

Thanks.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the daily requests per day limit was defined by Google. You can always [buy as many queries as you need](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing#requests-per-day-qpd-limits-have-ended-effective-june-11-2018).

Comment: Thank you @Steven, yes, it's a google limitation. I'm looking for a free service that will accept 40k addresses.

Comment: Googling "batch geocode csv" seemed to bring up a number of options. They don't appear to be `R` specific though.

Comment: Your options are limited, @AvraGoldman. Either pay a little bit to Google, live with the existing limitations and instability of the Nominatim demo access — or you can always setup your own OSM instance.